# how to check the file exists in postman

Tags: java, spring, hadoop, postman

I am using post man client with java. I want to test the file if exist or not in hadoop using postman.

Here is my program:

```
String arguments = "hdfs://nameservice1/user/ec2-user/" + bedroom + "-" + bathroom + "-" + area + "-" + city + "/part00000";
OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();
Request request = new Request.Builder()
    .url("http://ec2-52-34-14-38.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com:14000/webhdfs/v1/user/ec2-user/" + bedroom + "-" + bathroom + "-" + area + "-" + city + "/part-00000?user.name=ec2-user&op=OPEN")
    .build();
if (request.equals(arguments)) {
    com.squareup.okhttp.Response responses = null;
    responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(responses);
    String output = "Prediction Value is " + responses.body().string();
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
} else {
    oozie objOz = new oozie(bedroom, bathroom, area, city);
    String response = objOz.callOozie();
    System.out.print("The Predicted Value is :" + response);
    com.squareup.okhttp.Response responses = null;
    responses = client.newCall(request).execute();
    System.out.println(responses);
    String output = "Prediction Value is " + responses.body().string();
    return Response.status(200).entity(output).build();
}
```

The if else part doesn't work.

Comment: what you mean with `The if else part is not works`???

Comment: `OPEN` is a request to **download** the file, with a HTTP 307 redirect from the NameNode to one of the DataNodes. It's not the proper way to test whether the file exists (and is not a directory). RTFM: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/WebHDFS.html

Comment: And what does Oozie have to do with HDFS??????

Comment: that is else part..I want to check the file if exist or not using post man